# How to shift a graph along the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot time-series data. Here is the sample code:

```
ax2 = pyplot.subplot(212)
true_targets = pyplot.plot(test_y[:, 0, :])
guessed_targets = pyplot.plot(test_y_hat[:, 0, :], linestyle='--')
```

And it produces the following graph:

[image: plot as I have it now]

I want to shift the graph to the right along x-axis (start from 1 instead of 0).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just use `plot` with a vector that specifies the x values:

```
plot(x_values, y_values, linestyles etc)
```

instead of just

```
plot(y_values, linestyles etc)
```

Of course, `x_values` and `y_values` need to have the same length. You can easily ensure that by doing something like

```
plot(range(1,1+len(y_values)), y_values, linestyles etc)
```

I generally often find myself in a situation where integers don't cut it as x coordinates, so I often use numpy (`import numpy`) and do

```
x_values = numpy.linspace(lower, upper, n_points)
```

and `n_points` is usually just `len(y_values)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem here, but if you just want your xaxis to start at 1 instead of 0 (without changing any of your values) you can just set the x limit on your axes:

```
ax2.set_xlim(1,len(test_y_hat))
```

You can have some conditional logic to set the upper limit on the x axis instead of getting the length of the vector like I did above