# Shifting start position of X Axis of line chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, x-axis

I want to shift the start position of the red line from "FEB-2020" to "JAN-2021". Currently this is my code and a picture of my current output. Basically Shorten the period of the whole graph to the dates stated above.

```
# plot daily vaccinated
fig, ax1= plt.subplots(1,figsize=(20,10))
# set up
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain') #changing the tick figure from le 6 to millions
plt.setp(ax1, xticks= np.arange(0, 680, 30), xticklabels=vac_dates)
# plot chart
ax1.plot(vaccinated['received_at_least_one_dose'], label= 'Total Vaccinated', c='Red')
# axis and legend settings
ax1.set_ylabel('population (millions)', size= 14)
ax1.set_title('Monthly Vaccinated Numbers', size= 20)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid()

ax1.legend(loc="upper left")
##########################################################
# plot daily covid cases
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# np.arrange looks at the number of rows
plt.setp(ax2, xticks= np.arange(0, 1035, 31), xticklabels=dates)
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.plot(infected_update)

plt.xlabel('date', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('population (thousands)', fontsize=14)
 
plt.grid(False)

ax2.legend(['imported','local'], loc="upper right")
```

[image: Output from code]

I've tried using codes from the following links but it doesn't seem to work

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32434607/how-to-shift-a-graph-along-the-x-axis](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Because you have tagged `pandas` and I assume `vaccinated['received_at_least_one_dose']` is a series with datetime index, you should make use of the date transformation offered by `matplotlib`. Take a look at the example for [date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-date-py) to start. If you use this information you already have, you don't have to shift your data. Try to avoid `xticks= np.arange(0, 680, 30)` in your code. To give us the chance to reproduce, please add your data.

Comment: I have linked the two data sets here:

https://data.gov.sg/dataset/covid-19-case-numbers?resource_id=400a3eb4-8702-4050-9700-988bfea7a20f

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shivam5992/temp-datasets/master/covid19_sg.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic example using pandas, datetime index and matplotlib altogether. It is important to make sure the index is of type `DatetimeIndex`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4,5]}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-03', '2020-01-05', freq='D'))
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1,2,3,4,5], 'c':[1,2,2,2,2]}, index=pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-05', freq='D'))

# plot daily vaccinated
fig, ax1= plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,5))
# set up
ax1.plot(df.index, df['a'], label= 'Total Vaccinated', c='Red')
# axis and legend settings
ax1.set_ylabel('population (millions)', size= 14)
ax1.set_title('Monthly Vaccinated Numbers', size= 20)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid()

ax1.legend(loc="upper left")

##########################################################
# plot daily covid cases
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# np.arrange looks at the number of rows
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.plot(df_2.index, df_2['b'], color='Orange')

plt.xlabel('date', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('population (thousands)', fontsize=14)

plt.grid(False)
```

[image: datetime bases line plots]

This means in your case, you have to make sure to set `parse_dates=True` and set the index, when your read your data. Using `pd.read_csv()` this could look like

```
df = pd.read_csv('covid.csv', sep=',', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)
```

Because you have to DataFrames, you have so make yure both have a DatetimeIndex. Afterwards just replace the columns in the two calls with `ac.plot()`.

Comment:

If you want to plot all columns of a Dataframe, `ax2.plot(df_2.index, df_2)` works. If your want to select a subset of columns `ax2.plot(df_2.index, df_2[['b', 'c']])` is doing the job.

Comment: This is so good! your examples really helped a lot!